# Isomorphism between quotient modules implies equality of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I am currently working through Eisenbud's book "Commutative Algebra", where (on p. 73) I came across the following statement which seems to be absolutely clear and trivial, but I cannot see how this is true:

> Let $N$, $L$, $L'$ be submodules of a module $M$ (over a commutative ring with unity) where $L\supseteq L'$, and where $L/L'$ is simple.
>
> Suppose that $((N\cap L)+L')/L'$ is isomorphic to $L/L'$.
>
> Then, $(N\cap L)+L'=L$.

I don't see how this is true (if $L'$ is not trivial). Maybe I'm just not seeing some obvious thing here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For brevity denote $L'':=(N\cap L)+L'$. Note that $L'\leqslant L''\leqslant L$, so in particular $L''/L'$ is a submodule of $L/L'$. But $L/L'$ is simple, so we must either have either $L''/L'=L/L'$ or $L''/L'=0$. But, by the lemma below, $L''/L'=L/L'$ if and only if $L''=L$. Thus, if $L''/L'$ is not the zero module, then we must have $L''=L$.

But $L/L'$ is a simple module, and hence by definition is not the zero module. So if $L''/L'$ is isomorphic to $L/L'$, then it is not the zero module, and by the remark above this forces $L''=L$, as desired.

---

**Lemma:** Consider a chain of $R$-modules $A\leqslant B\leqslant C$. If $B/A=C/A$ then $B=C$.

**Proof:** We wish to show $C\leqslant B$, so fix any $c\in C$. By the assumption, $c+A\in B/A$, so there exists $b\in B$ such that $b+A=c+A$. In particular, $c\in b+A$, so $c=b+a$ for some $a\in A$. But $A\leqslant B$, so $b+a\in B$, ie $c\in B$, as desired. $\blacksquare$

Comment: The thing where I'm stuck is $L''/L'=L/L'$ iff $L''=L$. How can we conclude from the equality of quotients that $L''=L$?

Comment: hi @st.math; I've edited to address your question. hopefully it helps! :)

Comment: Yes, thank you! :)

Comment: @st.math my pleasure, happy it helped!!